# What is the logic behind aluminum siding?

Tags: siding

I have aluminum siding on my house (put on by a previous owner) that is starting to fall apart after 20 years.

My house is a [shingle house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingle_style_architecture). It is not painted, except the trim. I can understand the logic of using siding on a house to avoid having to paint it, but I don't really understand the logic of putting siding on a shingle house.

Should I just remove it? My fear is that if I go to a siding guy he is going to say he can't repair the siding and will want to replace all of it.

Comment: Your question title and the question posed in your post don't match. What are you asking? Is it a subjective question?

Comment: And what does "fall apart" mean? I've never seen metal siding decay.

Comment: What do other houses in the area look like (assuming you don't have the only shingle house locally). It may be that a previous owner put the siding up because they didn't like the look of shingles. Talk to a siding guy; you can get a recommendation, and you don't have to take their advice if you don't like it (be upfront, and be prepared to pay for his time if you just want a consultation)

Comment: Quotes are usually free. I would call at least 2 siding contractors and ask for a bid to repair. Contractors will talk with you to find your concerns and propose a path forward. If it is not what you want you are not obligated to do anything but you will now know some options and the cost. Other than chalking  and getting dented I have seen few problems with aluminum siding. One sales point is the additional insulation, The second low maintenance.

Comment: Hokey coverups (e.g. painting brick) are usually due to an ugly, expensive-to-repair flaw in the underlying surface.  Be prepared to peel back the aluminum siding and find problematic shingles.